# 2 diffrent layouts for same api version on android

Tags: android, api, layout, version, platform

both 2.3.3 and 2.3.4 platform versions, are API level 10. but, they have diffrent handling for right to left text. 
i have 2 layout files, one is for API 8 and one for API 10, but my question is, is it possible to have 2 diffrent layouts for the same API level, but diffrent platform versions (2.3.3 and 2.3.4)?

Comment: i don't think so ... you should check build version before inflaiting layout and choose a proprer one by yourself

Comment: i want to know what is the difference ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller 2.3.4 seems to flip the android:gravity attribute on RTL languages.